# (beginner) Sending information with event in libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm struggling with a pretty simple task: How to properly send information with a button press using object-oriented code.

I have a "ColorWindow"† holding a bunch of "ColorButton"†† objects. I need the button presses to send information about what the color of the pressed button was. I *think* the proper technique to use here is to fire off some sort of custom event that contains information or points to the ColorButton that fired it. I'm just not sure how to create a custom Event (or how to cause the rest of my code to receive it), or even whether that is what I should be doing.

Sorry for asking such a basic question, I'm pretty new to [edit:Java] and libGDX. I've been reading a lot of documentation and doing searches on my own trying to learn but at this point I really need to be shown the right direction.

† *A table extending the Scene2D Window*

†† *A widget extending the Scene2D Button that contains a Color attribute*

**Edit: The following seems to work just fine.**

```
public class ExampleButton extends Button
{
    public String exampleString

    public IconButton(Skin skin, String exampleString)
    {
        super(skin);
        this.exampleString = exampleString;
    }
}

        //add this where needed
        addListener(new ClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y)
            {
                //grabs a reference to the button from the event it fired
                Actor target = event.getTarget();
                //cast Actor into ExampleButton to access its contents
                ExampleButton btn = (ExampleButton)target;
                System.out.println(btn.exampleString);
                return true
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scene2D will already automatically fire Events that includes a reference to the button that started the event. You need an EventListener set up to react to the events, like this:

First, make sure you have member references to your various buttons. Then you can reference them in an EventListener.

```
private ColorButton colorButton0;
private ColorButton colorButton1;
//etc.

private EventListener colorButtonListener = new EventListener(){
    public boolean handle (Event event){
        Actor actor = event.getTarget();
        if (actor == colorButton0)
            //do something
        else if (actor == colorButton1)
            //do something
        else
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Assign this listener to every ColorButton like this:

```
colorButton1.addListener(colorButtonListener);
```

By the way, Java and JavaScript are two completely different languages, and libgdx uses only Java.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am ashamed to say I didn't know there was a difference between Java and JavaScript... 


The context where I would be handling the event wouldn't have a reference to the buttons. Are events the correct way to pass information up through the object's parents or should I be using a totally different strategy for that sort of interaction?

Comment: It is the correct way if you don't want to reinvent the wheel. You can give the listener a reference to the context that will be reacting to the buttons and have it pass the button reference to some method in that context.

Comment: Thanks Tenfour. I added some code to the question to show what ended up working.

Comment: OK, just a tip: EventListener is nicer than ClickListener for traditional buttons in your menus where you want the traditional behavior of not firing if you move your finger off it before releasing. But this is usually not what you'd want for an in-game button in an action game.